# How to fill in observations following some condition

Tags: stata

```
   |caseid      |  i    |birth|preg |unwanted|
   | 1  22  2   |69     |  1  |0    |1
   | 1  22  2   |70     |  1  |1    |.
   | 1  22  2   |71     |  1  |1    |.
   | 1  22  2   |72     |  1  |1    |.
   | 1  22  2   |73     |  1  |1    |.
   | 1  22  2   |74     |  1  |1    |.
   | 1  22  2   |75     |  1  |1    |.
   | 1  22  2   |76     |  1  |1    |.
```

Here is an example of my data in Stata.

What I want to do is to `replace unwanted` equal to missing with 1 if `preg` is 1 and `unwanted` is 1 in the previous observation (not for `unwanted` = 0).

I tried:

```
bysort caseid (i) : replace unwanted = unwanted[_n+1] if unwanted = 1
```

It keeps saying it's invalid syntax.

Comment: What is illegal is using `=` not `==` to test equality. Your code is legal otherwise but not correct.

Comment: In Stata what you call rows are called observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str7 caseid float(i birth preg unwanted)
"1_22_2" 69 1 0 1
"1_22_2" 70 1 1 .
"1_22_2" 71 1 1 .
"1_22_2" 72 1 1 .
"1_22_2" 73 1 1 .
"1_22_2" 74 1 1 .
"1_22_2" 75 1 1 .
"1_22_2" 76 1 1 .
end

bysort caseid (i) : replace unwanted = unwanted[_n-1] if missing(unwanted) & preg==1

list, sepby(caseid) 

     +---------------------------------------+
     | caseid    i   birth   preg   unwanted |
     |---------------------------------------|
  1. | 1_22_2   69       1      0          1 |
  2. | 1_22_2   70       1      1          1 |
  3. | 1_22_2   71       1      1          1 |
  4. | 1_22_2   72       1      1          1 |
  5. | 1_22_2   73       1      1          1 |
  6. | 1_22_2   74       1      1          1 |
  7. | 1_22_2   75       1      1          1 |
  8. | 1_22_2   76       1      1          1 |
     +---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Good. Please accept the answer.